# Sort XML tag in correct order when shredding the XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xquery, sql-server-2019

I have a table with a `XML` column there is no standard structure for the XML file as the XML tag can come multiple times or come at N number of nested levels. I am using an UDF query from  this link [How can I get a list of element names from an XML value in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266132/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-element-names-from-an-xml-value-in-sql-server). This UDF works great except the order in which the XML tag get inserted.

For this XML, it return the data based on alphabetical order

```
DECLARE @x XML  
SELECT @x = '
<books>
    <book id="101">
        <title>my book</title>
        <author>Myself</author>
    </book>
    <book id="202">
        <Writer>sample</Writer>
         <title>your book</title>      
         <author>you</author>       
    </book>
</books>'


;WITH cte AS 
( 
    SELECT 
        1 AS lvl,  
        x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Name,  
        CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS ParentName, 
        --CAST(1 AS INT) AS ParentPosition, 
        CAST(N'Element' AS NVARCHAR(20)) AS NodeType,  
        x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS FullPath,  
        x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')  
        + N'[' 
        + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NVARCHAR)  
        + N']' AS XPath,  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Position, 
        --x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Tree,  
        x.value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Value,  
        x.query('.') AS CurrentNode,         
        --x.query('*') AS t,  
        CAST(CAST(1 AS VARBINARY(4)) AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS Sort,  
        CAST(1 AS INT) AS ID  
    FROM 
        @x.nodes('/*') a(x)  
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        p.lvl + 1 AS lvl,  
        c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Name,  
        CAST(p.Name AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS ParentName, 
        --CAST(p.Position AS INT) AS ParentPosition, 
        CAST(N'Element' AS NVARCHAR(20)) AS NodeType,  
        CAST(p.FullPath + N'/' + c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS FullPath,  
        CAST(p.XPath + N'/'+ c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')+ N'['+ CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NVARCHAR)+ N']' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS XPath,  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Position, 
        --CAST( SPACE(2 * p.lvl - 1) + N'|' + REPLICATE(N'-', 1) + c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Tree,  
        CAST( c.value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) AS Value, 
        c.query('.') AS CurrentNode,  
        --c.query('*') AS t,  
        CAST(p.Sort + CAST( (lvl + 1) * 1024 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) * 2) AS VARBINARY(4)) AS VARBINARY(MAX) ) AS Sort,  
        CAST((lvl + 1) * 1024 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) * 2) AS INT)  
    FROM 
        cte p  
    CROSS APPLY 
        CurrentNode.nodes('/*/*') b(c)
), cte2 AS 
(
    SELECT 
        lvl AS Depth,  
        Name AS NodeName,  
        ParentName, 
        --ParentPosition, 
        NodeType,  
        FullPath,  
        XPath,  
        Position, 
        --Tree AS TreeView,  
        Value,  
        CurrentNode AS XMLData,  
        Sort, ID  
    FROM 
        cte  
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        p.lvl,  
        x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        p.Name, 
        --p.Position, 
        CAST(N'Attribute' AS NVARCHAR(20)),  
        p.FullPath + N'/@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        p.XPath + N'/@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        1, 
        --SPACE(2 * p.lvl - 1) + N'|' + REPLICATE('-', 1)  
        --+ N'@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        x.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        NULL,  
        p.Sort,  
        p.ID + 1  
    FROM 
        cte p  
    CROSS APPLY 
        CurrentNode.nodes('/*/@*') a(x)  
)  
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Sort, ID) AS ID,  
    ParentName,-- ParentPosition,
    Depth, NodeName, Position,   
    NodeType, FullPath, XPath, --TreeView, 
    Value, XMLData 
FROM
    cte2
```

The result will order the (Id =4) tag before (ID =5) tag but in xml the tag order is different. Similarly the other XML block  the   tag come last instead of first.

```
ID  ParentName  Depth   NodeName    Position    NodeType    FullPath    XPath   Value   XMLData
    1   NULL    1   books   1   Element books   books[1]    NULL    <books><book id="101"><title>my book</title><author>Myself</author></book><book id="202"><Writer>sample</Writer><title>your book</title><author>you</author></book></books>
    2   books   2   book    1   Element books/book  books[1]/book[1]    NULL    <book id="101"><title>my book</title><author>Myself</author></book>
    3   book    2   id  1   Attribute   books/book/@id  books[1]/book[1]/@id    101 NULL
    4   book    3   author  1   Element books/book/author   books[1]/book[1]/author[1]  Myself  <author>Myself</author>
    5   book    3   title   1   Element books/book/title    books[1]/book[1]/title[1]   my book <title>my book</title>
    6   books   2   book    2   Element books/book  books[1]/book[2]    NULL    <book id="202"><Writer>sample</Writer><title>your book</title><author>you</author></book>
    7   book    2   id  1   Attribute   books/book/@id  books[1]/book[2]/@id    202 NULL
    8   book    3   author  1   Element books/book/author   books[1]/book[2]/author[1]  you <author>you</author>
    9   book    3   title   1   Element books/book/title    books[1]/book[2]/title[1]   your book   <title>your book</title>
    10  book    3   Writer  1   Element books/book/Writer   books[1]/book[2]/Writer[1]  sample  <Writer>sample</Writer>
```

But if comment the Xpath and Position field from the UDF it give us the correct order as shown below

```
   DECLARE @x XML  
SELECT @x = '
<books>
    <book id="101">
        <title>my book</title>
        <author>Myself</author>
    </book>
    <book id="202">
        <Writer>sample</Writer>
         <title>your book</title>      
         <author>you</author>       
    </book>
</books>'


;WITH cte AS (  
SELECT 
        1 AS lvl,  
        x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Name,  
        CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS ParentName, 
        --CAST(1 AS INT) AS ParentPosition, 
        CAST(N'Element' AS NVARCHAR(20)) AS NodeType,  
        x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS FullPath,  
        --x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')  
        --+ N'[' 
        --+ CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NVARCHAR)  
        --+ N']' AS XPath,  
        --ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Position, 
        --x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Tree,  
        x.value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Value,  
        x.query('.') AS CurrentNode,         
        --x.query('*') AS t,  
        CAST(CAST(1 AS VARBINARY(4)) AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS Sort,  
        CAST(1 AS INT) AS ID  
FROM @x.nodes('/*') a(x)  
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
        p.lvl + 1 AS lvl,  
        c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Name,  
        CAST(p.Name AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS ParentName, 
    --CAST(p.Position AS INT) AS ParentPosition, 
        CAST(N'Element' AS NVARCHAR(20)) AS NodeType,  
        CAST(p.FullPath + N'/' + c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS FullPath,  
        --CAST(p.XPath + N'/'+ c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')+ N'['+ CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        --ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NVARCHAR)+ N']' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS XPath,  
        --ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        --ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Position, 
        --CAST( SPACE(2 * p.lvl - 1) + N'|' + REPLICATE(N'-', 1) + c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Tree,  
        CAST( c.value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) AS Value, 
        c.query('.') AS CurrentNode,  
        --c.query('*') AS t,  
        CAST(p.Sort + CAST( (lvl + 1) * 1024 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) * 2) AS VARBINARY(4)) AS VARBINARY(MAX) ) AS Sort,  
        CAST((lvl + 1) * 1024 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) * 2) AS INT)  
FROM cte p  
CROSS APPLY CurrentNode.nodes('/*/*') b(c)) 
, cte2 AS (  
                                            SELECT 
                                            lvl AS Depth,  
                                            Name AS NodeName,  
                                            ParentName, 
                                            --ParentPosition, 
                                            NodeType,  
                                            FullPath,  
                                            --XPath,  
                                            --Position, 
                                            --Tree AS TreeView,  
                                            Value,  
                                            CurrentNode AS XMLData,  
                                            Sort, ID  
                                            FROM cte  
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
        p.lvl,  
        x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        p.Name, 
        --p.Position, 
        CAST(N'Attribute' AS NVARCHAR(20)),  
        p.FullPath + N'/@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        --p.XPath + N'/@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        --1, 
        --SPACE(2 * p.lvl - 1) + N'|' + REPLICATE('-', 1)  
        --+ N'@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        x.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        NULL,  
        p.Sort,  
        p.ID + 1  
FROM cte p  
CROSS APPLY CurrentNode.nodes('/*/@*') a(x)  
)  
SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Sort, ID) AS ID,  
        ParentName,-- ParentPosition,
        Depth, NodeName, --Position,   
        NodeType, FullPath,-- XPath, --TreeView, 
        Value, XMLData 
FROM cte2
```

Below Result will display the correct order but it misses the XmlPath field which I need for further processing as it uniquely identify the element.

```
ID  ParentName  Depth   NodeName    NodeType    FullPath    Value   XMLData
1   NULL    1   books   Element books   NULL    <books><book id="101"><title>my book</title><author>Myself</author></book><book id="202"><Writer>sample</Writer><title>your book</title><author>you</author></book></books>
2   books   2   book    Element books/book  NULL    <book id="101"><title>my book</title><author>Myself</author></book>
3   book    2   id  Attribute   books/book/@id  101 NULL
4   book    3   title   Element books/book/title    my book <title>my book</title>
5   book    3   author  Element books/book/author   Myself  <author>Myself</author>
6   books   2   book    Element books/book  NULL    <book id="202"><Writer>sample</Writer><title>your book</title><author>you</author></book>
7   book    2   id  Attribute   books/book/@id  202 NULL
8   book    3   Writer  Element books/book/Writer   sample  <Writer>sample</Writer>
9   book    3   title   Element books/book/title    your book   <title>your book</title>
10  book    3   author  Element books/book/author   you <author>you</author>
```

Please can you help to sort the correct order with Xpath field.

Thanks

Comment: `ORDER BY FullPath` maybe? What exactly are you trying to do that you need to shred the XML in this fashion? Do you know the format of the XML upfront?

Comment: ORDER BY FullPath doesn't work as it sort the Nodes in alphabetical order. I don't know the xml structure upfront  and I am extracting around 100,000 of xml files and shred into a table and extract specific details. The above sample is just to replicate the order by issue  which I am currently facing.

Comment: Relying on `ROW_NUMBER()` to number the elements isn't reliable. If you want to find the sequential indices of child nodes relative to their parent you'd use XPath similar to `x.value('for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i]) + 1', 'int')`. Rejigging your `Sort` calculations to something like `FORMAT(x.value('for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i]) + 1', 'int'), N'D3')` and `p.Sort + N'.' + FORMAT(c.value('for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i]) + 1', 'int'), N'D3')` would give you output similar to `001`, `001.002` and `001.002.003` which is still sortable alphanumerically.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning `let $i := .` is more straightforward (and faster maybe?) than `for $i in .`

Comment: You say "extract specific details" what specific details? If you know what it is you want to extract then you could probably do this much more simply

Answer (score 0):

I just added a derived table to get the XPath after the sorting  done in the inner query. Below is the query which sort the child nodes in correct order

```
DECLARE @x XML  
SELECT @x = '
<books>
    <book id="101">
        <title>my book</title>
        <author>Myself</author>
    </book>
    <book id="202">
        <Writer>sample</Writer>
         <title>your book</title>      
         <author>you</author>       
    </book>
</books>'


;WITH cte AS (  
SELECT 
        1 AS lvl,  
        x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Name,  
        CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS ParentName, 
        --CAST(1 AS INT) AS ParentPosition, 
        CAST(N'Element' AS NVARCHAR(20)) AS NodeType,  
        x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS FullPath,  
        x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')  
        + N'[' 
        + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NVARCHAR)  
        + N']' AS XPath,  
        --ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Position, 
        --x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Tree,  
        x.value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Value,  
        x.query('.') AS CurrentNode,         
        --x.query('*') AS t,  
        CAST(CAST(1 AS VARBINARY(4)) AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS Sort,  
        CAST(1 AS INT) AS ID  
FROM @x.nodes('/*') a(x)  
UNION ALL 
SELECT                      
lvl,  
Name,
ParentName,
NodeType,
FullPath, 
CAST(XPath + N'/'+ Name + N'['+ CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name 
ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NVARCHAR)+ N']' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS XPath,
Value, 
CurrentNode,
Sort, 
ID
FROM(

SELECT 
        p.lvl + 1 AS lvl,  
        c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Name,  
        CAST(p.Name AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS ParentName, 
    --CAST(p.Position AS INT) AS ParentPosition, 
        CAST(N'Element' AS NVARCHAR(20)) AS NodeType,  
        CAST(p.FullPath + N'/' + c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS FullPath, 
        p.XPath AS XPath,
        --CAST(p.XPath + N'/'+ c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')+ N'['+ CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') ORDER BY (select 1)) AS NVARCHAR)+ N']' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS XPath,  
        --ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        --ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Position, 
        --CAST( SPACE(2 * p.lvl - 1) + N'|' + REPLICATE(N'-', 1) + c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Tree,  
        CAST( c.value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) AS Value, 
        c.query('.') AS CurrentNode,  
        --c.query('*') AS t,  
        CAST(p.Sort + CAST( (lvl + 1) * 1024 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) * 2) AS VARBINARY(4)) AS VARBINARY(MAX) ) AS Sort,  
        CAST((lvl + 1) * 1024 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) * 2) AS INT)  AS ID
FROM cte p  
CROSS APPLY CurrentNode.nodes('/*/*') b(c))  AS D)
, cte2 AS (  
SELECT 
    lvl AS Depth,  
    Name AS NodeName,  
    ParentName, 
    --ParentPosition, 
    NodeType,  
    FullPath,  
    XPath,  
    --Position, 
    --Tree AS TreeView,  
    Value,  
    CurrentNode AS XMLData,  
    Sort, ID  
FROM cte  
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
        p.lvl,  
        x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        p.Name, 
        --p.Position, 
        CAST(N'Attribute' AS NVARCHAR(20)),  
        p.FullPath + N'/@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        p.XPath + N'/@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        --1, 
        --SPACE(2 * p.lvl - 1) + N'|' + REPLICATE('-', 1)  
        --+ N'@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        x.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        NULL,  
        p.Sort,  
        p.ID + 1  
FROM cte p  
CROSS APPLY CurrentNode.nodes('/*/@*') a(x)  
)  
SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Sort, ID) AS ID,  
        ParentName,-- ParentPosition,
        Depth, NodeName, --Position,   
        NodeType, FullPath, XPath, 
        --TreeView, 
        Value, XMLData 
FROM cte2
```